# Devise Token Auth confirmation email link expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-confirmable, devise-token-auth

I am currently developing a website and i have a problem with te confirmation link with devise token auth.

Everything is working right, after someones registers they get an email with a confirmation link. This link is confirming and working properly BUT when this link expires (i set it up in the configuration with config.confirm_within = 1.day ) or someone clicks this link again they get a "Routing error". So i suppose there should be a way of redirecting to the homepage when that link expires and maybe showing a message saying that they have to ask for the email confirmation again..

i have this confirmation routes:

```
new_api_user_confirmation GET    /api/auth/confirmation/new(.:format)   devise_token_auth/confirmations#new
api_user_confirmation     GET        /api/auth/confirmation(.:format)   devise_token_auth/confirmations#show
                          POST       /api/auth/confirmation(.:format)   devise_token_auth/confirmations#create
```

I use the last route POST for resending the email and it is working, but the other to routes are not working and that makes sense because i am using API. But there should be a redirect url for when you get an error

Any thoughts? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the `DeviseTokenAuth::ConfirmationsController#show` and redirect to root_path

DeviseTokenAuth [ConfirmationsController#show](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/confirmations_controller.rb#L6)

```
class ConfirmationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::ConfirmationsController    
  def show
    ...
    else
      # raise ActionController::RoutingError, 'Not Found'
      redirect_to :root_path
    end
  ...
```

in routes

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
  # confirmations:  'devise_token_auth/confirmations',
  confirmations:  'confirmations',
```

[devise-token-auth docs](https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage/overrides)

Comment: Perfect... i did this yesterday after lots of reading.. your answer is correct. now i am struggling with other thing... i would love to send a message depending on the error.. they have in the controller a variable called >resource< and inside somewhere there is an error message.. i am trying to send this one as a querystring...  or simply send somehitng like redirecto_to login_path(message: "my message") but this message depeding on the error that could be link expired or user already confirm.. i am sorry maybe i am asking for to much now.. but do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: you can use `@resource.errors` object. To get first message `@resource.errors.full_messages.first`. [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages)

Comment: thank you so much MASTER!!.. everything works perfect !!.